# Change Fragments within ViewPager (Android 4.2)

Tags: android, user-interface

I want to change fragments inside a ViewPager which is below a 3 column ActionBar (I chose the standard 3 column starting project in the new wizard). I have researched whole stackoverflow and couldn't find a good solution...

Basically I have 3 screen A B C. On screen B I want to implement a button to switch to another page:

1) A B C
2) A X C

With the new Android APIs there should be an easy way of doing it right(Nested Fragments)? Please help with a small code example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ViewFlipper http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html inside the layout.

```
<ViewFlipper>
   <LinearLayout1/>
   <LinearLayout2/>
</ViewFlipper>
```

onButtonClick you can call

```
viewFlipper.ShowNext();
viewFlipper.ShowPrevious();
```

And also you can add animation while page transition.

Comment: ViewPagers aren't interactive, where ViewPager's allow swipes.  Probably not what he wants.

Comment: He mentioned ABC -> AXC. ViewFlipper will work perfectly in that case. Because I am using that in my app.

Answer (score 0):

you could use setCurrentItem method on your viewPager object inside your button click listener:

```
myViewPager.setCurrentItem(2); // integer 2 is a page number which is your fragment
```